# ag-grid JS not showing even though height set with css grid layout

Tags: html, css, ag-grid, grid-layout

I would like to have an `ag-grid` below a graph on my webpage.

If I don't manually set the `height` property of the `ag-grid` it doesn't show in this [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/chapo/svf2Lucb/).

I initialize the grid as such :

```
let moves_data = res.result;
let gridOptions = {
    rowData: moves_data,
    columnDefs: [
      {headerName: 'date_peak',field: 'date_peak'},
      {headerName: 'date_through',field: 'date_through'},
      {headerName: 'udl_peak',field: 'udl_peak'},
      {headerName: 'udl_through',field: 'udl_through'},
      {headerName: 'value',field: 'value'},
    ]
  };
let movesGrid = new agGrid.Grid(document.querySelector("#results"), gridOptions);
movesGrid.gridOptions.api.sizeColumnsToFit();
movesGrid.gridOptions.columnApi.autoSizeAllColumns();
```

The `HTML` is:

```html
  <div id="results_container">
    <div id="graph-container" class="dygraph-container">
      <div id="graph"></div>
    </div>
    <div id="results" class="ag-theme-balham" style="height:300px;"></div>
  </div>
```

and the `CSS` that I would expect to take care of the height issue is :

```css
#results_container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: 400px;
}
```

How can I get the `ag-grid` to show using only the CSS grid-layout properties ? If I can't use those, why is that the case ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's couple of ways to set height for your grid.

1- Set `domLayout: 'autoHeight'` on grid property (**It's a nightmare for large numbers of rows**)

When you're setting autoHeight you're able to set min height for your grid but it's not possible to specify a max height.

As described in [it's documentation](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-width-and-height/#auto-height):

> When `domLayout='autoHeight'` then your application should not set height on the grid div, as the div should be allowed flow naturally to fit the grid contents. When auto height is off then your application should set height on the grid div, as the grid will fill the div you provide it.
>
> - As you set different numbers of rows into the grid, the grid will resize it's height to just fit the rows.
> - As the grid height exceeds the height of the browser, you will need to use the browser vertical scroll to view data (or the `iFrames` scroll if you are looking at the example embedded below).
> - The height will also adjust as you filter, to add and remove rows.
> - If you have pinned rows, the grid will size to accommodate the pinned rows.
> - Vertical scrolling will not happen, however horizontal scrolling, including pinned columns, will work as normal.
> - It is possible to move the grid into and out of 'full height' mode by using the `api.setDomLayout()` or by changing the bound property `domLayout`.

2- Set it in your scripts (**Somehow better than autoheight**):

```
gridOptions.api.setDomLayout('normal');
document.querySelector('#results').style.height = '400px';
```

3- If you prefer to use css you can do it using general css rules like below:

```
.ag-theme-balham .ag-cell
{
    height: 300px;
}
```

4- Or, If you like to use grid layout framework you can find it's example [here](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-responsiveness/#inside-css-grid-container).

Here is the final view implemented on your example (I reduced the amount of data to not touch the the edge of SO character limit):

```js
$(function() {

  let res = {
 "data": [{
   "date": "2000-01-03",
   "value": 101.45
 }, {
   "date": "2000-01-04",
   "value": 103.22
 }, {
   "date": "2000-01-05",
   "value": 104.14
 }, {
   "date": "2000-01-06",
   "value": 105.23
 }, {
   "date": "2000-01-07",
   "value": 105.34
 }, {
   "date": "2000-01-10",
   "value": 105.16
 }, {
   "date": "2000-01-11",
   "value": 105.95
 }, {
   "date": "2000-01-12",
   "value": 105.79
 }, {
   "date": "2000-01-13",
   "value": 106.17
 }, {
   "date": "2000-01-14",
   "value": 105.87
 }, {
   "date": "2000-01-17",
   "value": 104.9
 }, {
   "date": "2000-01-18",
   "value": 105.67
 }, {
   "date": "2000-01-19",
   "value": 105.32
 }, {
   "date": "2000-01-20",
   "value": 105.47
 }, {
   "date": "2000-01-21",
   "value": 104.78
 }, {
   "date": "2000-01-24",
   "value": 105.57
 }, {
   "date": "2000-01-25",
   "value": 106.04
 }, {
   "date": "2000-01-26",
   "value": 105.66
 }, {
   "date": "2000-01-27",
   "value": 105.12
 }, {
   "date": "2000-01-28",
   "value": 107.13
 }, {
   "date": "2000-01-31",
   "value": 107.32
 }, {
   "date": "2000-02-01",
   "value": 107.85
 }, {
   "date": "2000-02-02",
   "value": 108.16
 }, {
   "date": "2000-02-03",
   "value": 107.56
 }, {
   "date": "2000-02-04",
   "value": 107.19
 }, {
   "date": "2000-02-07",
   "value": 108.62
 }, {
   "date": "2000-02-08",
   "value": 109.47
 }, {
   "date": "2000-02-09",
   "value": 108.79
 }, {
   "date": "2000-02-10",
   "value": 109.27
 }, {
   "date": "2000-02-11",
   "value": 108.82
 }, {
   "date": "2000-02-14",
   "value": 108.96
 }, {
   "date": "2000-02-15",
   "value": 109.22
 }, {
   "date": "2000-02-16",
   "value": 109.44
 }, {
   "date": "2000-02-17",
   "value": 110.56
 }, {
   "date": "2000-02-18",
   "value": 111.09
 }],
 "result": [{
   "date_peak": "2000-01-13",
   "date_through": "2000-01-03",
   "udl_peak": 106.17,
   "udl_through": 101.45,
   "value": 4.652538196155742
 }, {
   "date_peak": "2000-02-02",
   "date_through": "2000-01-21",
   "udl_peak": 108.16,
   "udl_through": 104.78,
   "value": 3.2258064516129004
 }, {
   "date_peak": "2000-02-08",
   "date_through": "2000-02-04",
   "udl_peak": 109.47,
   "udl_through": 107.19,
   "value": 2.127064091799613
 }, {
   "date_peak": "2000-02-21",
   "date_through": "2000-02-09",
   "udl_peak": 111.26,
   "udl_through": 108.79,
   "value": 2.2704292673958903
 }, {
   "date_peak": "2000-03-14",
   "date_through": "2000-02-24",
   "udl_peak": 105.12,
   "udl_through": 111.37,
   "value": -5.611924216575382
 }, {
   "date_peak": "2000-03-23",
   "date_through": "2000-03-14",
   "udl_peak": 107.24,
   "udl_through": 105.12,
   "value": 2.0167427701674123
 }, {
   "date_peak": "2000-03-31",
   "date_through": "2000-03-23",
   "udl_peak": 102.78,
   "udl_through": 107.24,
   "value": -4.158895934352847
 }, {
   "date_peak": "2000-04-11",
   "date_through": "2000-03-31",
   "udl_peak": 106.92,
   "udl_through": 102.78,
   "value": 4.028021015761829
 }, {
   "date_peak": "2000-04-17",
   "date_through": "2000-04-11",
   "udl_peak": 104.54,
   "udl_through": 106.92,
   "value": -2.2259633370744436
 }, {
   "date_peak": "2000-05-03",
   "date_through": "2000-04-17",
   "udl_peak": 109.02,
   "udl_through": 104.54,
   "value": 4.285440979529365
 }]
  }

  let moves_data = res.result;
  let gridOptions = {
 rowData: moves_data,
 columnDefs: [{
  headerName: 'date_peak',
  field: 'date_peak'
   },
   {
  headerName: 'date_through',
  field: 'date_through'
   },
   {
  headerName: 'udl_peak',
  field: 'udl_peak'
   },
   {
  headerName: 'udl_through',
  field: 'udl_through'
   },
   {
  headerName: 'value',
  field: 'value'
   },

 ]
  };
  let movesGrid = new agGrid.Grid(document.querySelector("#results"), gridOptions);
  movesGrid.gridOptions.api.sizeColumnsToFit();
  movesGrid.gridOptions.columnApi.autoSizeAllColumns();

  //graph with arrows
  let udl_data = res.data;
  let g = new Dygraph(
 document.getElementById("graph"),
 udl_data.map((x) => {
   let res = [];
   for (let col in x) {
  if (x.hasOwnProperty(col)) {
    if (col.toLowerCase() === "date") {
   res.push(new Date(x[col]));
    } else {
   res.push(parseFloat(x[col]));
    }
  }
   }
   return res;
 }), {
   labels: Object.keys(udl_data[0]),
   underlayCallback: (canvas, area, g) => {
  moves_data.map((row) => {
    let coordsA = g.toDomCoords(new Date(row.date_through), parseFloat(row.udl_through));
    let coordsB = g.toDomCoords(new Date(row.date_peak), parseFloat(row.udl_peak));

    let add_height = -15;
    coordsA[1] += add_height;
    coordsB[1] += add_height;

    canvas.beginPath();
    canvas.moveTo(coordsA[0], coordsA[1]);
    canvas.lineTo(coordsB[0], coordsB[1]);
    canvas.strokeStyle = "black";
    canvas.stroke();

    let radius = 5;

    canvas.beginPath();
    canvas.moveTo(coordsA[0], coordsA[1]);
    canvas.arc(coordsA[0], coordsA[1], radius, 2 * Math.PI, Math.PI, false);
    canvas.fillStyle = "green";
    canvas.fill();

    canvas.beginPath();
    canvas.moveTo(coordsB[0], coordsB[1]);
    canvas.arc(coordsB[0], coordsB[1], radius, Math.PI, 2 * Math.PI, false);
    canvas.fillStyle = "red";
    canvas.fill();

  });
   }
 }
  );
  let the_width = $("#tabs-research-tabs-udl_move-graph-container").css("width");
  $("#tabs-research-tabs-udl_move-graph").css("width", the_width);
  g.resize();

})
```

```css
.container {
display: grid;
grid-template-columns: 1fr 2fr 1fr;
grid-template-rows: 50vh;
width: 100%;
}

#left {
 grid-row: 1/1;
 grid-column: 1/1;
 background: gray;
}

#results {
 grid-row: 1/1;
 grid-column: 2/2;
 overflow: hidden;
}

#right {
 grid-row: 1/1;
 grid-column: 3/3;
 background: gray;
}
```

```html
<div id="results_container">
<div id="graph-container" class="dygraph-container">
  <div id="legend" class="dygraph-legend"></div>
  <div id="graph"></div>
</div>
<div class="container">
  <div id="left"></div>
  <div id="results" class="ag-theme-balham"></div>
  <div id="right"></div>
</div>
</div>
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://cdn01.dailycaller.com/wp-includes/js/jquery/jquery.js?ver=1.7.2'></script>
```

**If the example is error prone you can find working example [here](https://jsfiddle.net/7ads2uhy/) in fiddle**

Comment: have slightly edited the question to make sure the answer is based on `grid-layout` CSS

Comment: Thks for taking the time @MasLoo but this is not what I expected. I know how to set the height of the ag-grid through the means you showed. But I was expecting it to be compatible with the `grid-layout` framework

Comment: No, it's not compatible with grid layout framework. Sorry for taking your time.

Comment: Then that settles the issue once and for all which is still interesting information ! Thks for your help.

Comment: I should take my words back. It's possible to implement grid layout. take a look at [this](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-responsiveness/#inside-css-grid-container)

Comment: nice that's the one. Do you want to put that as an answer with a modified fiddle ?

Comment: Sure. Answer updated. I don't know how to reference jQuery here, but I've put a link of working example below the answer.